# Generating triangular number using iteration in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function in Haskell to generate  triangular number, I am not allowed to use recursion, I am supposed to use iteration

here is my code ...

```
triSeries 0 = [0] 
triSeries n = take n $iterate (\x->(0+x)) 1
```

I know that my function after iterate is wrong .
But It has been hours looking for a function, any hint please?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) could be a hint, where something like

```
triangular :: Int -> Int
triangular x = x * (x + 1) `div` 2
```

could be got from.

`triSeries` could be something like

```
triSeries :: Int -> [Int]
triSeries x = map triangular [1..x]
```

and works like that

```
> triSeries 10
[1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55]
```

Talking about `iterate`. Maybe there is some way to use it here, but as John said, `foldl` would be sufficient. Take a look at [this page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold), what are you looking is in the very beginning.

Comment: I don't think this closed-form solution counts as iteration.  Although it's certainly the best approach.

Comment: If the homework task's statement contain "not to use recursion" (hard to imagine for what particular reason it could be used here) this solution could be interpreted like valid.

Comment: – ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ thanks a lot I used your help and I got it working :)

Comment: triSeries 0 = [0]
    triSeries n = map triangular $take n $iterate (+1) 1
       where triangular x = x * (x + 1) `div` 2

Comment: you still don't need to have `triSersies 0 = [0]`

Comment: It's impossible to write this without recursion *happening* (`map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs`), but this is a valid way to write it without *doing* recursion yourself. Still, I don't understand why you would require someone to not use recursion in a language where all such solutions use recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing out some triangular numbers

- T(1) = 1
- T(2) = 1 + 2
- T(3) = 1 + 2 + 3

An iterative process to generate `T(n)` is to start from `[1..n]`, take the first element of the list, and add it to a running total.  In a language with mutable state, you might write:

```
def tri(n):
  sum = 0
  for x in [1..n]:
    sum += x
  return sum
```

In Haskell, you can iteratively consume a list of numbers and accumulate state via a `fold` function (`foldl`, `foldr`, or some variant).  Hopefully that's enough to get started with.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is meant by "recursion is not allowed, use iteration". All functions that appear to be "iterative" are recursive inside.

`iterate` in all your uses can only modify the input with a constant, and `iterate (+1) 1` is the same as `[1..]`. Consider using a `Data.List` function that can combine a number from infinite range `[1..]` and the previously computed sum to produce a infinite list of such sums:

T_i=i+T_{i-1}

This is definitely cheaper than `x*(x+1) div 2`

Consider using a `Data.List` function that can produce an infinite list of finite lists of sums from a infinite list of sums. This is going to be cheaper than computing a list of 10, then a list of 11 repeating the same computation done for the list of 10, etc.